# FOSUserBundle event REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE not triggered

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I wanted to set password automatically when one register the form. So I use REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE to trigger the event. Unfortunately it's not working.

Listener:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;
/**
 * @param \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager
 */
public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE => 'onRegistrationInit',
    );
}

public function onRegistrationInit(UserEvent $userEvent)
{
    $user = $userEvent->getUser();

    $user->setPassword('abcdeffffff');

}
```

Services:

```
#src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
acme_user.registration:
    class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
    arguments:
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber}
```

So the password is not setting and it shows the password should not be blank.

What am I doing wrong? Any help!

EDIT:

The problem was I was defining service at the wrong place.

Instead of `src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`, It should be `app/config/services.yml`.

I saw `src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`in http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html, But was not working for me!

Comment: are you using the current symfony 3.3 version?

Comment: @lordrhodos nope I'm using 3.2.8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong, but I think your service definition uses [features from Symfony 3.3](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service) but you are using [Symfony `3.2.8`](http://symfony.com/doc/3.2/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service), e.g.

> New in version 3.3: The ability to configure an argument by its name ($adminEmail) was added in Symfony 3.3. Previously, you could configure it only by its index (2 in this case) or by using empty quotes for the other arguments.

Try updating your service definition to:

```
#src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    acme_user.registration:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber}
```

And a remark: as you are actually using a subscriber you should rename the class `RegistrationListener` to `RegistrationSubscriber`.